# How can a common trends be detected and filtered from multiple spectra data?

Tags: filters, python, background-subtraction

I'm looking at spectral data collected through Cavity ring-down spectroscopy. I'm comparing a few samples of similar analytes and expect slightly different peak heights and trends. However, there are peaks and valleys that are present in all samples that are artifacts of the instrument the data was collected on. Is there any filtering method that can detect the common shapes and remove them, perhaps something that leverages the variability of the differential of each?

I'm working in python so any language specific library would be helpful as well.

[image: Processed Data]

Edit:
Here's a figure of the raw data, as well as a zoomed in figure showing the valleys I was referring to. The processed data was generated by first applying a filter on the second derivative to remove harsh noise spikes, then Fourier Smoothing with a Gaussian Kernel is used to remove general noise.

[image: Raw Data]
[image: Raw Data Zoomed]

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  I would call this "calibration" of the instrument: removing systematic measurement errors. Can you give us more detail on what the data looks like **before** processing? And, perhaps, how you get from the pre-processed data to the processed data?